# Why is this .obj loader not drawing anything but the included .obj?

Tags: opengl, models

I've been adapting a tutorial on .obj file loading on the windows system to glut.

The thing's not drawing a thing except the "Foot.obj" file that the tutorial included and I'm going kinda nuts trying to figure out where's the fault. I'd appreciate [a look into the code](http://www.filedropper.com/ripobj_2).

To try loading a different .obj just change the line

```
#define FILE_NAME_1 "Foot.obj"
```

in `Main.cpp`. I included the .obj files I've been trying to load into the VS project.

edit: [codepad link to Main.cpp](http://codepad.org/uXKt9de1)

Comment: I really doubt many people are going to **download** the code. Use code tags and place it in your question, or use codepad/pastebin on the forever-stay-up-there setting?

Comment: Yeah, I thought the same thing. The code is long though, and it's split across several .cpp files. I'll try to post the most relevant parts.

Comment: Well, some helpful guy on gamedev.net did download the thing. Dude, this isn't a virus. I don't wanna get booted out StackExchange. http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=591112

Comment: Asking for a step that's beyond just reading what's in the question or providing a link to something in a web browser (consider pastebin or something similar) is going to reduce the amount of responses you get.  People are lazy.

Comment: I wasn't saying it was a virus, I was simply saying that people are mostly not going to bother helping someone if it means they have to do a lot of work.

Comment: I think It's actually easier to debug loading the VS project file, I tried slicing the thing and it ended up being a pain to read.

Comment: It has very little to do with people being lazy, it's more to do with people who like answering good questions wants to see some major involvement first: http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: What other obj files? How do you create them? Have you run your diffing tool over them and compared to the foot? What if you modify the foot obj instead? Is there a simple position-in-space issue?

Answer (score 2):

I'd start by looking at the file you are trying to load. My experience with different exporters of .obj files is that they can play a little loose with the formats structure/order. Make sure the data looks the same between the two.

If you are loading the non-foot files, but just failing to render then another thing to check is if the foot model is entirely triangulated, and if the other models you are loading have faces defined by more than 3 verts.

Comment: +1 first thought here, what kind of obj files are we talking about? There are many that use that ubiquitous extension and the "format" I'm thinking of has very loose specs where things like line-breaks can differ and mess things up...